# export to excel a Power BI refresh automatically

Tags: excel, powerbi

Is there a way export to excel a Power BI refresh automatically?

I know that we can refresh data gateway automatically but can we export data from power bi automatically to excel file?

Comment: You can connect Excel to your online data model so that it stays up to date.

Comment: You can connect Excel to your online data model by e.g. using the Power BI publisher for Excel. Now you only need to set up a scheduled refresh of your local Excel workbook and synchronize it with your gateway refresh.

Comment: I need to export many reports to Csv and send it as email. I do it within SSRS using subscription. I don't know if it's possible to do it with powerbi. I can't add access to all persons to powerbi.